# Event study- overvalued or undervalued stock

Tags: event-study

I am an doing event study and calculated abnormal return with the help of market model [$r_\text{actual} - (\alpha+\beta r_m)$]. Then I calculated a t-stat and next CAR (cumulative abnormal return). Now I have two doubts:

1. I am confused when there is overpriced or underpriced security.
2. What more can I interpret from this analysis?

thank you Regards 
Priya

Comment: Event study does not care about overvalued/undervalued securities, it is done to show if there is an effect on prices from the "event" and whether that effect is positive or negative. That is interesting information. Event study is an average over 100s (or more) events & companies, some may be overvalued some undervalued, it does not matter and is in any case difficult/impossible to determine.

Comment: thank you sir .